# Maven could not build due to .lastupdated extension

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

We have a project with multiple sub modules. It is unable to build the project due to some modules dependencies are downloaded with .lastUpdated extension.

I cleaned local repository and tried several times but again i see jar files with extension .lastUpdated extension. however its working fine in my colleague machine.

Does it work if i copy complete local repository from another machine? I know that i can experiment that but expecting some suggestions why it is causing problem then.

Comment: The `.lastUpdated` extension shows the time when the artifacts has been checked the last time...did you get a build failure? If yes please post the output here ...do you get `missing dependencies` message or something similar...

Comment: I have copied local repository from my colleague machine. Now it works fine. I have no idea what went wrong.